# flashing new firmware to TL-WR841N

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I want to flash a new firmware to my TP-LINK TL-WR841N router version 14.1. So I have tried to install firmware from [DD-WRT](https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/). I have tried all other versions available here as version 14 is not available in the dd wrt website. When I try to upgrade firmware from webui I am getting an error `4503 The uploaded file was not accepted by the device`. Why this error is getting? Router has 4 MB flash memory, 32MB RAM and Ralink APSoC. I have serial console access as well.  Could you please suggest any other method to reflash my router firmware. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: He’s referring to the hardware (or product) revision. // This is a very low-performance device. But I’m sure you know that already.

Answer (score 2):

From https://dd-wrt.com/support/router-database/ you can see that v13 is not supported and v14 is not here .

And if you look at betas version of ddwrt , you can not find v14 ( Jun 15 2020 ) .

https://download1.dd-wrt.com/dd-wrtv2/downloads/betas/2020/06-15-2020-r43420/

On OPEN-WRT,  you can see that from https://openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr841nd , it seems that v14 is only supported in dev/snapshot version .
This router is very cheap, and  he  has only 4MB of flash disk .

**This is not anymore recommended for openwrt**

please see https://openwrt.org/supported_devices/openwrt_on_432_devices

You need to use  [magebuilder](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/imagebuilder) to build a very small firmware you can find some advices [here](https://openwrt.org/docs/guide-user/additional-software/saving_space)

Comment: @Tim_Stewart but if the router is not supported on OpenWRT you will have almost no change to have a support on DD-WRT

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize he was talking about the router revision number... And in that case, yea this is about the only chance to get third party firmware running on it. Lol I'm surprised he didn't brick it  by flashing with other revisions firmware.